# Enable dot and Tab in textboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I have text boxes which only allow to enter numeric values. I handled it using a JavaScript. But it doesn't allow me to enter dot and tab movement. I need those two  as well. How to change this code to enter dot symbol and tab movement.

```
function CheckNumeric(e) {

    if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else // Fire Fox
    {
        if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, check how it behaves when copy & paste

Comment: Can you just use the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) input? - Only available in HTML5

Comment: yes this script works and it only allows to enter numeric values

Answer (score 0):

**this code is tested and works..this may help u..!!**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function onlyDotsAndNumbers(txt, event) {
          var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
          if (charCode == 46) {
              if (txt.value.indexOf(".") < 0)
                  return true;
              else
                  return false;
          }
          if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
              return false;

          return true;
      }
```

```
> <asp:TextBoxID="txt1"runat="server"onkeypress="return onlyDotsAndNumbers(this,event)"/>
```

Comment: i tried this code but this code allows to enter non numeric values as well